# Entity Framework: Populate existing object instance

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Here's how I would normally retrieve an object from the database:

```
Dim Prod = (From P In Db.Products Where P.ProductID = 123).FirstOrDefault()
```

Now, I need to implement a "load" instance method that can be called like so:

```
Dim Prod = New Product()
Prod.Load(123)
```

How would I go about populating the existing Product object from the database? I'm trying to avoid using reflection or any messy copy methods.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Public Overridable Sub Load(ByVal ProductID As Integer)
    Db.Products.Where(Function(P) P.ProductID = ProductID).Populate(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about why you need to implement it this way?  Most people usually recommend that you keep your entities insulated from the details of your data access layer.  What's wrong with the normal way of retrieving the object that you list at the top?

Comment: I'm updating an existing framework from ADO.NET to Entity Framework - so the Load functions need to be there to be compatible with existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you'll be able to get is to use [`DbEntityEntry.Reload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reload%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on your entity object, followed by using the [`DbEntityEntry.Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.reference%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [`DbEntityEntry.Collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.collection%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) methods to get instances of [`DbReferenceEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbreferenceentry%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [`DbCollectionEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcollectionentry%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) for each navigation property and collection on your entity, which you can use to reload those members. Something like this:

```
Public Overridable Sub Load(ByVal ProductID As Integer)

    ' Set primary key
    Me.ProductID = ProductID

    ' Reload scalar/complex properties
    Db.Entry(Me).Reload()

    ' Reload navigation properties
    Db.Entry(Me).Reference(Function(p) p.Entity).Load()
    Db.Entry(Me).Reference(Function(p) p.OtherEntity).Load()

    ' Reload navigation collections
    Db.Entry(Me).Collection(Function(p) p.ChildEntities).Load()
    Db.Entry(Me).Collection(Function(p) p.OtherChildEntities).Load()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I just had to attach the object first using Db.Products.Attach(Me).